# Pinia Vue Composition API, accessing state returns undefined

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api, pinia

I have this Pinia store defined as:

```js
export const useNotesStore = defineStore('notes', () => {
  const initialData = computed(() => ({
    banner: "",
    title: "",
    group: "",
    newGroup: "",
    content: "",
    favorite: false,
  }))
  const newNote = ref({ ...initialData.value });
  const parsed = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes")) || [];
  const notes = ref([...parsed]);

  const addNote = (payload) => {};

  return {
    initialData,
    newNote,
    notes,
    addNote,
  };
});
```

And, I am importing and using the store in my page as follows:

```js
import { useNotesStore } from '@/stores/notes';
const notesStore = useNotesStore();

const handleSelectBanner = (value) => {
    // If I simply log, it has values.
    console.log(notesStore.newNote);

    // this line right here is what's throwing an error.
    notesStore.newNote.value.banner = value;

}
```

This is the output when logging `notesStore.newNote`.

```
Proxy(Object) {banner: '', title: '', group: '', newGroup: '', content: '', …}
```

However, when I handle button click in my template, and access the state in my Pinia. I get an error:

```js
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'banner')
```

Afaik, when we access the state, we always use `.value`, but why is mine undefined? Is there something I am missing here?

PS: I am learning Pinia with Vuejs.

Comment: It's more consistent when using store options instead of store function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I figured it out.

Even though the `newNotes` state of our Pinia is reactive with `ref({ ... })`, we do not access its value using `.value` **outside of the store**, instead, we use the state directly like the below:

```js
const notesStore = useNotesStore();
notesStore.newNotes.banner = 'Your Value Here';
```

This is because the Pinia store will **unwrap** that for us.

However, we still need to use `.value` if we access the state **INSIDE** the store like:

```js
// this is a method defined in the store.
const addNote = (payload) => {
     notes.value.push(payload);
};
```

I'll just leave the post here as it might help others with similar problem.